# SQL query to fetch repeat column values within time frame

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an eCommerce website where I am getting lot of fraud orders.. I'd like to pull out those `Order_No`.

Here is my query

```
 SELECT 
     O.Order_No, O.Customer_ID, O.DateOrdered, O.IPAddress,
     C.FirstName, C.LastName, CD.nameoncard
 FROM 
    Order_No O
 INNER JOIN 
    CardData CD ON O.card_id = CD.id
 INNER JOIN 
    Customers C ON O.customer_id = C.customer_id   
 ORDER BY
    O.order_no desc
```

Here's the criteria I want to follow:

1. If the `customer_id` repeats more than once in 6hrs
2. If the IPAddress repeats more than once in 6hrs
3. If the Lastname is NOT found in Nameoncard

Can someone help please?

Comment: And for the 6 hours, you can use datediff for example from date 0, and then divide it by 6 to get the groups.

Comment: can you add some input data ?

Comment: customer can order multiple orders with in a day right even ip address  and custid is same but difference of order min 6 hours ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the query:

```
select * from
(
select b.order_no,b.dateordered,a.customer_id, C.FirstName, C.LastName, cd.nameoncard from order_no as a
left join order_no as b on a.customer_id=b.customer_id
inner join carddata as cd on b.customer_id=cd.customer_id
INNER JOIN Customers C ON b.customer_id = C.customer_id
where a.order_no < b.order_no
and datediff(hour,a.dateordered,b.dateordered) between 0 and 6
union
select b.order_no,b.dateordered,a.customer_id, C.FirstName, C.LastName, cd.nameoncard from order_no as a
left join order_no as b on a.IPAddress=b.IPAddress
inner join carddata as cd on b.customer_id=cd.customer_id
INNER JOIN Customers C ON b.customer_id = C.customer_id
where a.order_no < b.order_no
and datediff(hour,a.dateordered,b.dateordered) between 0 and 6
union
select a.order_no,a.dateordered,a.customer_id, C.FirstName, C.LastName, cd.nameoncard from order_no as a
inner join carddata as cd on a.customer_id=cd.customer_id
INNER JOIN Customers C ON a.customer_id = C.customer_id
where charindex(C.LastName,cd.nameoncard) = 0
) as abc
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
WITH Tmp (Order_No, Customer_id, DateOrdered, IPAddress, FirstName,    LastName, NameOnCard) 
AS
(
SELECT Ord.Order_No, Ord.Customer_Id, Ord.DateOrdered, Ord.IPAddress,
    Cust.FirstName, Cust.LastName, CustData.NameOnCard
FROM Order_No Ord
INNER JOIN Customers Cust 
ON 
Cust.Customer_Id = Ord.Customer_Id
INNER JOIN 
CardData CustData
ON CustData.Id = Ord.Card_Id
)
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM Tmp a
INNER JOIN Tmp b 
ON a.Order_No <> b.Order_No 
AND a.Customer_Id = b.Customer_Id
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, a.DateOrdered, b.DateOrdered) >= 6
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM Tmp c
INNER JOIN Tmp d 
ON c.Order_No <> d.Order_No 
AND c.IPAddress = d.IPAddress
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, c.DateOrdered, d.DateOrdered) >= 6
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT e.*
FROM Tmp e
WHERE ISNULL(e.NameOnCard,'') = ''
```

Comment: hi.. Thanks for your reply.. the query is very slow and its taking lot of time to execute..

Comment: Is Order_No, Customer_Id and IPAddress columns are indexed ?

Please remove distinct from the select statement and check

Comment: i modified some of your query and it worked.. i m posting the answer